# Issue with joining tables in hadoop , where driver table has 10M records and child tables are left joined having 1M records

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

Facing an issue with joining 3 tables in hadoop , where left most table has 10M records and each right table has 1M records. The right most tables are left join with parent table.

```
SELECT distinct Table1.cid,Table2.gdtyp,Table3.ager,Table3.edcd FROM (SELECT 
distinct(cid) FROM Table1  WHERE Table1.orgcd='T002' AND 
(Table1.cacttrdt>=19980101 AND Table1.cacttrdt<=20171120) limit 2) Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 Table2 ON (Table2.cid=Table1.cid)  LEFT JOIN Table3 Table3 
ON (Table3.cid=Table1.cid)
```

The above query is getting stuck during mapreduce.
Have set auto convert join to false.

Comment: is it giving any error or exception ??

Comment: no its not giving any error, query is getting stuck in a stage.There are 4 stages, its getting stuck in 3rd stage always

Comment: did you check the job status while it is running ? 
wait for it to return any error.

else apply compression techniques, vectorization, mapjoin(if it is ok to use) and then run the query.

Comment: Yes checked there are no errors in the logs, weird thing is, same query getting executed from hive CLI, but getting stuck when executed from beeline or from external application

Comment: create stage tables from the main tables with limited records and run the same query on the stage tables.. if the query runs successfully then atleast we can conclude that there is memory issue and use some other ways.. if the query wont get executed then there must be some other issue.

Comment: Just to add, same query is getting completed without getting stuck from Hive CLI.

Comment: oh.. then many records the query is returning??

and is the whole tab or window or just the job getting strucked? are you using cloudera?

after the job/tab/window gets strucked are you able to access other windows or tab in the browser which you are running the query?

Comment: if you are facing the above issues. then the GUI where you are running the query is unable to accomodate to display all records. thats why it is getting strucked. try the limit clause and run.. it works!

Comment: The problem is not with GUI, external batch job is running, while creating hive connection its getting stuck, but same query is running flawlessly from hive CLI

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized query execution improves performance of operations like joins, scans, aggregations and filters, by performing them in batches of 1024 rows at once instead of single row each time.

Introduced in Hive 0.13, this feature significantly improves query execution time, and is easily enabled with two parameters settings:

set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;

Also use the TEZ as the execution engine than Mapreduce.

Comment: Our current requirement is to use mapreduce engine, tried with above mentioned properties, still the query is stuck at where it was before

Comment: Just to add, same query is getting completed without getting stuck from Hive CLI.